foot of perpendicular using cosine
We consider a triangle $\Delta_\textbf{ABC}$ in $\mathbb{E}^2$ and use the usual notations for the side lengths and the angles of the triangle. Let $\textbf{L}$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $\textbf{C}$ to $\textbf{AB}$
Prove that:
$ \textbf{L} = \textbf{A} + \frac{b \cos(\alpha)}{c} (\textbf{B} - \textbf{A}) $
I know that the question is perhaps a bit too easy, but somehow I can't figure it out right now :/
I did not come up with the coefficient   $\frac{b \cos(\alpha)}{c}$
would be grateful for any help :)

I don't know what your notation means. You don't seem to be using 'the usual notation for side lengths and angles' as I understand it (eg side a opposite angle A). Are you involving vectors here?

$c$ is the length of $B-A$, so dividing by it gives the unit vector; then, multiplying by the appropriate length gives the vector from $A$ to foot $L$. Thus, "all we need to do" is justify that $b \cos\alpha$ that "appropriate length". (Restricting attention to non-obtuse angle at $A$) In $\triangle CAL$, side $AC$ is the hypotenuse, and $AL$ is the leg adjacent to $\angle A$; so, $|AL|=|AC|\cos\angle A=b\cos\alpha$. (Draw a picture.) Note that when $\angle A$ is obtuse, the negative cosine does the correct thing by reversing the vector's direction, as $L$ is no longer between $A$ and $B$.

Thank you very much. Got it :)
